# Error message: The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I need to read data from a table in a database and bind it to a listview. Unfortunately I get this error:

> The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors
>   defined.

I couldn't find anything that would fix the problem.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["User_interface_Proftaak.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand table = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DATA ORDER BY Score", connection);
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader datareader = table.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (datareader.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(datareader["Name"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(datareader["Score"].ToString());

            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you working with visual studio ?

Comment: ho yeah you can't comment... anoying

Comment: answer yourself then delete your answer just so we can communicate

Comment: When do you get this error? When running the program or in the designer?

Comment: He cannot comment yet...

Comment: Post your reply as an answer to your own question, then we'll copy it in the comments, i don't see anything else that can save you right now....

Comment: yeah like Thomas said would be a good way to communicate with us... if you put a break point on your using(), then push  F10 until it crashes, just so we know what function does crash

Comment: @AntoinePelletier anyone can comment on their *own* posts. Probably OP does not want to comment...

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted.  Somewhere in your code, you have `new SqlDataReader()`